# Sub or Function is not defined vb6

Tags: vb6

Why am I getting an error "Sub or Function is not defined"...Here is my code

FORM2

```
Option Explicit
Public Report As New CrystalReport1
Public mvCn As New ADODB.Connection

 Public Function printReport()

 Dim strConnectionString As String
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim strScript As String

 strConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB............"

 mvCn.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
 mvCn.CommandTimeout = 0
 mvCn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
 mvCn.Open

 strScript = strScript & "SELECT * FROM employee" & vbCrLf

 Set rs = mvCn.Execute(strScript)

 Report.Database.SetDataSource rs
 Report.AutoSetUnboundFieldSource crBMTNameAndValue

 CRViewer1.ReportSource = Report
 CRViewer1.ViewReport

 Set Report = Nothing

 End Function
```

Form 1.....Call my function "printReport" here

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()

printReport

End Sub
```

The error message goes here "Private Sub Command1_Click()"

Comment: you should put your public functions in a module, not in forms, BTW: Form2.printReport would work, but you should better avoid that Start here: [Anatomy of a VB Project](http://www.thevbprogrammer.com/Ch02/02-01-Anatomy.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is your printReport function defined?  If it's in a class module, then you need to instantiate an instance of the class then call printReport as a method of that class.  For instance:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim oClass As New Class1

  oClass.printReport

End Sub
```

Or you can place your printReport function in a module, then you don't instantiate it or call it as a method - you would instead call it as you have in your click event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply....My printReport function defined in my form 2

Comment: You don't show any Form2 code.  Please edit your post to describe Form2, and how you are creating and displaying it.

Comment: Where and how are you displaying Form2?  Is it being displayed modal or non-modal? You have not provided that information.

Answer (score -1):

A procedure can be called in such a simple way.[As you have called is correct]

Eg.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Test1
End Sub

Sub Test1()
    MsgBox "Test1"
End Sub
```